# Function generic constrained by argument type

Tags: typescript

Observe this typescript code:

```
class cli<T extends string> {}
let dist = function <T extends string>(m:T,c:cli<T>):void {

};
let a:cli<"foo"> = new cli();
dist("bar",a);
```

The error that I'd like is that "bar" is not "foo", however if you actually check there is in fact no error because dist inferred the type argument `"foo" | "bar"`. I'm trying to figure out how to deal with this.

It seems to me that one way would be to make the `dist` function a method of `cli` but in my actual application doing so would be... unsavory.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure if that can be done by inferring. The type system in TypeScript is duck typing, it is not strict typing as in Java or C#. Since `foo` and `bar` are both string, the compiler will widen it so that it will work.

One way to restrict the type is by explicitly specifying the type: `dist<'bar'>('bar', a)`. That will produce error. But I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: Well the trouble with doing that is that it relies on the user to make the type explicit, so its not really saving them from any errors you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having them share the same type argument `T` means they are both bounded by the same constraint rather than having one define the boundary of the other. If you want the type of `m` to be bounded by the type argument passed to `cli` you should specify them as separate type arguments, one depending on the other. Example:

`let dist = function <T extends string, U extends T>(m: U, c: cli<T>): void { };`